# Health Service on wear os

Tags: android, wear-os, healthconnect

I create app in wear os using Health Service sdk. When watch enter ambientMode service not get me datas from service. How to fix this problem. I read documentation of this it say should set BatchingMode.HEART_RATE_5_SECONDS to batchingModeOverrides but this not helped

```kotlin
    inner class AmbientModeHandler {
        internal fun onAmbientEvent(event: AmbientEvent) {
            when (event) {
                is AmbientEvent.Enter -> onEnterAmbient()
                is AmbientEvent.Exit -> onExitAmbient()
                is AmbientEvent.Update -> onUpdateAmbient()
                else -> {}
            }
        }

        private fun onEnterAmbient() {
            // Note: Apps should also handle low-bit ambient and burn-in protection.
            unbindViewsFromService()
            setAmbientUiState(true)
            performOneTimeUiUpdate()
        }

        private fun onExitAmbient() {
            performOneTimeUiUpdate()
            setAmbientUiState(false)
            bindViewsToService()
        }

        private fun onUpdateAmbient() {
            performOneTimeUiUpdate()
        }
    }

    private fun performOneTimeUiUpdate() {
        val service = checkNotNull(serviceConnection.exerciseService) {
            "Failed to achieve ExerciseService instance"
        }
        updateExerciseStatus(service.exerciseState.value)
        updateLaps(service.exerciseLaps.value)

        service.latestMetrics.value?.let { updateMetrics(it) }

        activeDurationCheckpoint = service.activeDurationCheckpoint.value
        updateChronometer()
    }
```